# Python3 How to start second thread and continuous receive result in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous

Good day everyone,

I am banging my head on this for what feels like eternity but cannot solve this issue. Hence I thought I may as well ask devs more experienced than me. My situation is this:

I have one python script that continuously identifies people's faces through a video stream and creates a dict object with the name and the time the preens was recognised - called recogniser_class.py. This one has a class with a method to retrieve the identified persons called returnIdentifiedFaces()

I have a second python (called tkapp.py) script that consists of a main script and two classes. The first one creates a screen with some information on it - mainly weather, clock and personalised news and calendar events. And the second one called recognizerAsync() Now these two last items, news and calendar events, should be personalised by the name of the user and that "user" shall of course be identified by this very first script by calling that method returnIdentifiedFaces()
This I tried to achieve by creating this second class recognizerAsync() within tkapp.py to instantiate recognizer_class class and have it run as a thread.

I can start both scripts alone and they work - obviously the tkapp without personalisation :-)

Now here is the code from within the script tkapp to instantiate the recogniser class and start the recognition process as a thread

```
class recognizerAsync(Thread):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    print("starting up recogizer from callRecognizerThread")
    
    if (use_user == True):
        #myRecognizer = recognizer(consoleLog, debugMsg, run_from_flask)
        self.myRecognizer = the_recognizer.recognizer(True, True, True)

def run(self):
    print("starting up recogizer from callRecognizerThread")
    
    if (use_user == True):
        #myRecognizer = recognizer(consoleLog, debugMsg, run_from_flask)
        self.myRecognizer.faceRecognizer()

def getUser(self):
    self.myRecognizer.printRecognizedFaces()
    return(self.myRecognizer.returnRecognizedFaces())
```

As said, this code is within the tkapp.py script.

I changed this to using a queue so now the code looks like this, but it still does NOT execute correctly. The returnRecognizedFaces method from the external recogniser class is never executed. This is the new code:

```
class recognizerAsync(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(recognizerAsync,self).__init__()
        print("starting up recogizer from callRecognizerThread")
        
        if (use_user == True):
            #myRecognizer = recognizer(consoleLog, debugMsg, run_from_flask)
            self.myRecognizer = the_recognizer.recognizer(True, True, True)
            
            
    def run(self):
        print("starting up recogizer from callRecognizerThread")
        
        
        if (use_user == True):
            self.myRecognizer.faceRecognizer()
            while (True):
                if ( not q.full() ):
                    fd = self.myRecognizer.returnRecognizedFaces()
                    print(f"PRODUCER: putting into queue {fd}")
                    q.put(fd)
                else: 
                    print("ERROR :: Queue q is full")
```

Once the tkapp.py is started it instantiates it's own GUI class and then starts the recogniser_class.py thread with this code snippet:

```
# start the gui
window = Tk()
window.title("Smart Mirror")
window.geometry('1024x768')
window.configure(background=gui_back_color)

window.bind("<Escape>", close_escape)

mirror = GUI(window)
mirror.setupGUI()

# update the news calling returnRecognizedFaces()
window.after(1000, mirror.updateNews)

face_thread = recognizerAsync()
face_thread.start()

window.mainloop()
```

This all works. So the GUI is created and the recognition of people is started (I assume as a thread)

The problem I have is that the moment this is executed, I can see in the log and console, that the recogniser_class.py is indeed identifying people, but I don't know how to query the result of the recognizer_class.

this is the code within tkapp.py that I thought should do the trick:

```
def updateNews(self):
    # cola the method to query the recognised person dictionary from recognizer_class.py
    self.user = recognizerAsync.getUser()
    print(f"got user {self.user} from recognizer")
    
    news_data = self.myNews.returnNews(self.user)
    if (len(news_data) > 0):
        GUI.news_today.configure(text=(f"Nachrichten für {self.user}"))
        GUI.news_number1.insert(INSERT, (f"{news_data[0]['title']}"))
    else:
        GUI.news_title.configure(text="Keine Nachrichten verfügbar")
   
    window.after(50000000, mirror.updateNews)
```

As said, this does not work and I really don't know how to do it right. This is the error I receive from this code:

```
File "./tkapp.py", line 271, in updateNews
    self.user = recognizerAsync.getUser()
TypeError: getUser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
starting face detection - press Ctrl C to stop
```

**I understand of course, that the recognizerAsync class is instantiated from the main script and therefore not available within the GUI class within the tkapp.py script - but how do I solve this issue????**

I hope someone can help me here,

Christian

Please find below the code of the tkapp.py

tkapp.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


# needed to source in the configuration from file config.py
from pathlib import Path
# time formatting for clock
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'de_DE.UTF-8')
import time
from time import strftime
from datetime import date, timedelta


# the TK Gui
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font
import pandas as pd

# needed to run the recognizer in background
from threading import Thread

# need to show images from the web
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from urllib.request import urlopen
from io import BytesIO

import Weather.weather_class as the_weather
import News.news_class as the_news
import Recognizer.recognizer_class as the_recognizer

# EVERY RUNTIME BEHAVIOUR IS SET IN THE CONFIG FILE config.py
config_file = 'config.py'

#
##  THE GUI CLASS SETS UP THE LABLES AND INSTANTIATES THE NEWS AND WEATHER CLASS
##  IT IS ALSO RESPONSIBLE FOR UPDATING THE SCREEN CONTENT
#
class GUI(Frame):
    largeFont = ''
    mediumFont = ''
    normalplusFont = ''
    normalFont = ''
    lightFont = ''
    identified_person = 'nil'   # the dict we should get back from recognizer
    user = 'nil'                # a simple name string we pass to other functions
    
    # module pathes etc.
    weather_icons_path = ''
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        
        self.largeFont = tkinter.font.Font(family=gui_font_large[0], size=gui_font_large[1])
        self.mediumFont = tkinter.font.Font(family=gui_font_medium[0], size=gui_font_medium[1])
        self.normalplusFont = tkinter.font.Font(family=gui_font_normalplus[0], size=gui_font_normalplus[1])
        self.normalFont = tkinter.font.Font(family=gui_font_normal[0], size=gui_font_normal[1])
        self.lightFont = tkinter.font.Font(family=gui_font_light[0], size=gui_font_light[1])

        # instantiate news and weather class
        if (show_weather == True):
            self.myWeather = the_weather.weather()
        if (show_news) == True:
            self.myNews = the_news.news()
        #if (use_user == True):
            #myRecognizer = recognizer(consoleLog, debugMsg, run_from_flask)
            #self.myRecognizer = the_recognizer.recognizer(True, True, True)

    def setupGUI(self):
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)
        
        if (show_weather == True):
            # Weather & news frame to contain weather/news info
            today_weather_frame = Frame(self, width=400, height=500, bg=gui_back_color)
            today_weather_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
            GUI.weather_headline = Label(today_weather_frame, text="Wetter...", fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color,
                                    font=self.mediumFont, justify=LEFT)
            GUI.weather_headline.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NW)
            
            GUI.weather_report = Label(today_weather_frame, text="Wetterbericht...", fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color,
                                    font=self.normalplusFont, justify=LEFT)
            GUI.weather_report.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
            
            today_weather_frame_details = Frame(self, width=400, height=500, bg=gui_back_color)
            today_weather_frame_details.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
            GUI.weather_temp = Label(today_weather_frame_details, text="Temperatur:", fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color,
                                    font=self.normalFont, justify=LEFT)
            GUI.weather_temp.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
            GUI.weather_temp_el = Label(today_weather_frame_details, text="...", fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color,
                                    font=self.normalFont, justify=LEFT)
            GUI.weather_temp_el.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
            
            GUI.weather_humidity = Label(today_weather_frame_details, text="Luftfeuchtigkeit:", fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color,
                                    font=self.normalFont, justify=LEFT)
            GUI.weather_humidity.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
            GUI.weather_humidity_el = Label(today_weather_frame_details, text="...", fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color,
                                    font=self.normalFont, justify=LEFT)
            GUI.weather_humidity_el.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
            
            GUI.weather_sunrise = Label(today_weather_frame_details, text="Sonnenaufgang:", fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color,
                                    font=self.normalFont, justify=LEFT)
            GUI.weather_sunrise.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
            GUI.weather_sunrise_el = Label(today_weather_frame_details, text="...", fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color,
                                    font=self.normalFont, justify=LEFT)
            GUI.weather_sunrise_el.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
            
            GUI.weather_sunset = Label(today_weather_frame_details, text="Sonnenuntergang:", fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color,
                                    font=self.normalFont, justify=LEFT)
            GUI.weather_sunset.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)
            GUI.weather_sunset_el = Label(today_weather_frame_details, text="...", fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color,
                                    font=self.normalFont, justify=LEFT)
            GUI.weather_sunset_el.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W)
            
            # the initial weather icon
            icon = PhotoImage(file=weather_icons_path+"partly-cloudy-day.gif")
            icon = icon.subsample(10)

            # Set up labels to hold weather icons
            GUI.icon_label = Label(today_weather_frame, borderwidth=0, image=icon)
            GUI.icon_label.photo = icon
            GUI.icon_label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
            
        empty_frame = Frame(self, width=200, height=500, bg=gui_back_color)
        empty_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        
        if (show_news == True):
            # Labels to hold news info
            news_frame = Frame(self, width=400, height=500, bg=gui_back_color)
            news_frame.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

            GUI.news_today = Label(news_frame, text="\nNachrichten:", fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color,
                                font=self.normalplusFont, justify=LEFT)
            GUI.news_today.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

            GUI.news_number1 = Text(news_frame, wrap=WORD, height=1, width=80, 
                                    fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color, bd=0,
                                    font=self.lightFont, highlightthickness=0)
            GUI.news_number1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

            GUI.news_number2 = Text(news_frame, wrap=WORD, height=1, width=80, 
                                    fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color, bd=0,
                                    font=self.lightFont, highlightthickness=0)
            GUI.news_number2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
            
            GUI.news_number3 = Text(news_frame, wrap=WORD, height=1, width=80, 
                                    fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color, bd=0,
                                    font=self.lightFont, highlightthickness=0)
            GUI.news_number3.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
            
            GUI.news_number4 = Text(news_frame, wrap=WORD, height=1, width=80, 
                                    fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color, bd=0,
                                    font=self.lightFont, highlightthickness=0)
            GUI.news_number4.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
            
            GUI.news_number5 = Text(news_frame, wrap=WORD, height=1, width=80, 
                                    fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color, bd=0,
                                    font=self.lightFont, highlightthickness=0)
            GUI.news_number5.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)
            
        # Adjust this width for spacing
        frame_placeholder = Frame(self, width=gui_width/4, height=10, bg=gui_back_color)
        frame_placeholder.grid(row=0, column=1)

        # Time frame to hold time & date in grid
        if (show_clock == True):
            time_frame = Frame(self, width=400, height=500, bg=gui_back_color)
            time_frame.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=NE)
            GUI.time_label = Label(time_frame, text=strftime("%H:%M", time.localtime()), fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color,
                                font=self.largeFont)
            GUI.time_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NE)

            GUI.date_label = Label(time_frame, text=strftime("%A, %d. %B", time.localtime()), fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color,
                                font=self.normalFont)
            GUI.date_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=NE)

        # Frame for calendar info
        if (show_calendar == True):
            calendar_frame = Frame(self, width=400, height=500, bg=gui_back_color)
            calendar_frame.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=NE)
            GUI.calendar_header = Label(calendar_frame, text='\nUpcoming events:', fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color,
                                        font=self.mediumFont)
            GUI.calendar_header.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NE)
            
            GUI.calendar_event1 = Label(calendar_frame, text='Loading calendar events...', fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color,
                                        font=self.normalFont)
            GUI.calendar_event1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=NE)
            
            GUI.calendar_event2 = Label(calendar_frame, text='Loading calendar events...', fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color,
                                        font=self.normalFont)
            GUI.calendar_event2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=NE)
            
            GUI.calendar_event3 = Label(calendar_frame, text='Loading calendar events...', fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color,
                                        font=self.normalFont)
            GUI.calendar_event3.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=NE)
            
            GUI.calendar_event4 = Label(calendar_frame, text='Loading calendar events...', fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color,
                                        font=self.normalFont)
            GUI.calendar_event4.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=NE)
            
            GUI.calendar_event5 = Label(calendar_frame, text='Loading calendar events...', fg=gui_fore_color, bg=gui_back_color,
                                        font=self.normalFont)
            GUI.calendar_event5.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=NE)

        self.configure(background=gui_back_color)

    def updateClock(self):
        GUI.time_label.configure(text=strftime("%H:%M", time.localtime()))
        GUI.date_label.configure(text=strftime("%A, %d. %B", time.localtime()))

        window.after(1000, mirror.updateClock)

    def updateWeather(self):
        # Updates the weather information
        weather_data = self.myWeather.returnWeather(self.user)
        GUI.weather_headline.configure(text=(f"Das {weather_data['city']} Wetter"))
        GUI.weather_report.configure(text=(f"{weather_data['weather_desc']}"))
        GUI.weather_temp_el.configure(text=(f"{weather_data['temp']}°C (Gefühlt: {weather_data['feels_like']}°C)"))
        GUI.weather_humidity_el.configure(text=(f"{weather_data['humidity']}%"))
        GUI.weather_sunrise_el.configure(text=(f"{weather_data['sunrise']}"))
        GUI.weather_sunset_el.configure(text=(f"{weather_data['sunset']}"))
        
        window.after(50000000, mirror.updateWeather)

    def updateNews(self):
        if (use_user == True):
            self.user = recognizerAsync.getUser()
            print(f"got user {self.user} from recognizer")

        news_data = self.myNews.returnNews(self.user)
        #print("size: " + str(len(news_data)) + "\n / result: " + str(news_data))
        if (len(news_data) > 0):
            if self.user != 'nil' and self.user != "":
                GUI.news_today.configure(text=(f"Nachrichten für {self.user}"))
            else:
                GUI.news_today.configure(text=(f"Aktuelle Nachrichten"))
            GUI.news_number1.insert(INSERT, (f"{news_data[0]['title']}"))
            GUI.news_number2.insert(INSERT, (f"{news_data[1]['title']}"))
            GUI.news_number3.insert(INSERT, (f"{news_data[2]['title']}"))
            GUI.news_number4.insert(INSERT, (f"{news_data[3]['title']}"))
            GUI.news_number5.insert(INSERT, (f"{news_data[4]['title']}"))
        else:
            GUI.news_title.configure(text="Keine Nachrichten verfügbar")
       
        window.after(50000000, mirror.updateNews)

    def updateCalendar(self):
        event_list = []
        if not events:
            print('No upcoming events found.')
        for event in events:
            event_str = ''
            start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
            start = start[0:10] # Remove unnecessary characters at end of string
            year = start.find('-')
            start_day = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%a %b %d')
            event_date = start[year + 1:year + 6]
            summary = event['summary'].encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii') # Remove emojis
            event_str += summary + ' | ' + start_day
            event_list.append(event_str)
        
        window.after(500000000, mirror.updateCalendar)

    def recognizer(self):
        self.myRecognizer.faceRecognizer()
    
    
class recognizerAsync(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("starting up recogizer from callRecognizerThread")
        
        if (use_user == True):
            #myRecognizer = recognizer(consoleLog, debugMsg, run_from_flask)
            self.myRecognizer = the_recognizer.recognizer(True, True, True)
    
    def run(self):
        print("starting up recogizer from callRecognizerThread")
        
        if (use_user == True):
            self.myRecognizer.faceRecognizer()
    
    def getUser(self):
        self.myRecognizer.printRecognizedFaces()
        return(self.myRecognizer.returnRecognizedFaces())

#
## MAIN SCRIPT RUN FROM HERE
#
app_config={}
print("setting config file to " + str(config_file))
exec(Path(config_file).read_text(encoding="utf8"), {}, app_config)

use_user = (app_config["use_user"])
show_news = (app_config["show_news"])
show_weather = (app_config["show_weather"])
show_calendar = (app_config["show_calendar"])
show_clock = (app_config["show_clock"])
analog_clock = (app_config["analog_clock"])

# GUI controls
gui_width = (app_config["gui_width"])
gui_height = (app_config["gui_height"])
gui_fullscreen = (app_config["gui_fullscreen"])
gui_back_color = (app_config["gui_back_color"])
gui_fore_color = (app_config["gui_fore_color"])

gui_font_large = (app_config["gui_font_large"])
gui_font_medium = (app_config["gui_font_medium"])
gui_font_normalplus = (app_config["gui_font_normalplus"])
gui_font_normal = (app_config["gui_font_normal"])
gui_font_light = (app_config["gui_font_light"])

# module pathes etc.
weather_icons_path = (app_config["weather_icons_path"])

def close_escape(event=None):
    print('Smart mirror closed')
    window.destroy()

print(f"starting GUI with {gui_width}x{gui_height}")
# start the gui
window = Tk()
window.title("Smart Mirror")
window.geometry((F'{gui_width}x{gui_height}'))
window.configure(background=gui_back_color)

#Removes borders from GUI and implements quit via esc
window.overrideredirect(1)
window.overrideredirect(0)
window.attributes("-fullscreen", gui_fullscreen)
window.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
window.focus_set()

window.bind("<Escape>", close_escape)

mirror = GUI(window)
mirror.setupGUI()


if (show_clock == True):
    window.after(1000, mirror.updateClock)
if (show_weather == True):
    window.after(1000, mirror.updateWeather)
if (show_news == True):
    window.after(1000, mirror.updateNews)
if (show_calendar == True):
    window.after(1000, mirror.updateCalendar)


if (use_user == True):
    face_thread = recognizerAsync()
    face_thread.start()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html), it is designed for inter-thread communication. Initialise a queue object before you split off the thread, and it will be available in both. When your recogniser thread finds a user, put it into the queue. In your update function, if the queue is not empty get the data and display it.

EDIT: Here is a minimal example:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
from time import sleep

queue = Queue()

class CountLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(text="Waiting")
        self.pack()

    def update(self):
        while not queue.empty():
            count = queue.get()
            self.configure(text=f"Count: {count}")
        self.master.after(1000, self.update)

def produce(queue):
    count = 0
    while (True):
        count += 1
        queue.put(count)
        sleep(1)

window = Tk()
label = CountLabel(window)
window.after(1000, label.update)
thread = Thread(target=produce, args=[queue]).start()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the quick answer. Just a general follow up on this: I see there is the queue from your link and there is also a multiprocessing.queue for use in multiprocessing, rather then multithreading approach. This leads me to wonder, given the context of my application with a GUI and a completely separate face recogniser - should I use multi threading, or rather multi processing here???

Comment: I must admit I do not know TK well at all. I believe you are doing multithreading, not multiprocessing, so `queue.Queue` should be preferred. But I may be wrong, so just try both. `multiprocessing.Queue` will work whether it's threads or a processes, but it uses more resources (a pipe instead vs memory sharing, IIRC).

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm unable to do this right, I think. I have setup the queue like in example https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Multithread/python_multithreading_Synchronization_Producer_Consumer_using_Queue.php but when I then call the returnRecognizedFaces Methode from the external recogniser class in the producer thread to put the element in the queue, nothing happens. It seems almost as if it is not executed. I updated the initial post to reflect the code change. Can you give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, your code is too big and too incomplete for me to debug. In the future, please consider making a [example]. I have provided a sample code that demonstrates the concept, which should be applicable to your use case.